# Add a TabNavigator with Stack Navigator (Version: 3.x)

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to add a tab Navigator in my project. It is a Weather app developped with React native. I tried to add a tab navigator in a screen but it never works. I tried to add it with a lot of tutorials...

Here's my code :

App.js

```
import SearchScreen from "./screens/search-screen";
import store from "./store";
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import {createStackNavigator, createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";
import AdvancedDetailScreen from "./screens/advanced-detail-screen";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
<Routes />
      </Provider>
  );
}
}

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Search : SearchScreen,
    Detail: AdvancedDetailScreen
},
    {
        initialRouteName: "Search",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);

const Routes = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

advanced-detail-screen.js :

```
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {View, Text, Button} from "react-native";
import {withNavigation} from "react-navigation";
import {getForecastWeatherByCity} from "../actions";
import {LineChart} from "react-native-chart-kit";
import {
    widthPercentageToDP as wp,
    heightPercentageToDP as hp
} from "react-native-responsive-screen";
import {kelvinToCelcius} from "../services/temperature";

class AdvancedDetailScreen extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        const city = this.props.navigation.getParam("city");
        this.props.getForecastWeatherByCity(city);
    }
    getTemperatures(){
        return this.props.forecastWeather.list.map(weather => {
            return (kelvinToCelcius(weather.main.temp))
        })
    }
    getHumidity(){
        return this.props.forecastWeather.list.map(weather => {
            return (kelvinToCelcius(weather.main.humidity))
        })
    }
    getLabels(){
        return this.props.forecastWeather.list.map((_,index) => {
            let day = index / 8
            return index === 0 ?  "t" : index % 8 === 0 ? "t+" + day + "j" : ""
        })
    }
    renderChart(data){
        return(
            <LineChart
                data={{
                    labels: this.getLabels(),
                    datasets: [
                        {
                            data
                        }
                    ]
                }}
                width={wp("90%")} // from react-native
                height={hp("30%")}

                yAxisInterval={1} // optional, defaults to 1
                chartConfig={{
                    backgroundColor: "#e26a00",
                    backgroundGradientFrom: "#fb8c00",
                    backgroundGradientTo: "#ffa726",
                    decimalPlaces: 2, // optional, defaults to 2dp
                    color: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
                    labelColor: (opacity = 1) => `rgba(255, 255, 255, ${opacity})`,
                    style: {
                        borderRadius: 16
                    },
                    propsForDots: {
                        r: "6",
                        strokeWidth: "2",
                        stroke: "#ffa726"
                    }
                }}
                bezier
                style={{
                    marginVertical: 8,
                    borderRadius: 16
                }}
            />
        )
    }
    goBack = () => {
        this.props.navigation.goBack();
};
    renderCharts(){
        return(
            <View style={{alignItems:"center", justifyContent: "center"}}>
                <Text style={{fontSize: 30, paddingTop: hp("1%")}}>
                    {this.props.forecastWeather.city.name} 5 days forecast
                </Text>
                <Text style={{marginBottom: hp("2%"), fontSize: 20}}>
                    Temperatures (C°)
                </Text>
                {this.renderChart(this.getTemperatures())}
                <Text style={{marginBottom: hp("2%"), fontSize: 20}}>
                    Humidity (%)
                </Text>
                {this.renderChart(this.getHumidity())}
                <Button onPress={this.goBack} title="Back" containerStyle={{marginTop: hp("1%"), width:wp("90%")}} />
            </View>
        )
    }
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={{justifyContent: "center", alignItems: "center", flex: 1}}>
                {this.props.forecastWeather ? this.renderCharts() : <Text>Loading...</Text>}
            </View>);
    }
}

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
        forecastWeather: state.weather.forecastWeather
    };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getForecastWeatherByCity
};

export default withNavigation(connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(AdvancedDetailScreen));
```

And my search-screen.js :

```
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import MapView from 'react-native-maps';
import {SearchBar} from "react-native-elements";
import {
    widthPercentageToDP as wp,
    heightPercentageToDP as hp
} from "react-native-responsive-screen";
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import {getCurrentWeatherByCity} from "../actions/index";
import WeatherCard from "../components/weather-card";

const DEFAULT_COORD = {
    lat: 48.859268,
    lng: 2.347060
};
class SearchScreen extends React.Component {
    state={search: ""};
    updateSearch = search => {
        this.setState({search})
    };
    submitSearch = () => {
        this.props.getCurrentWeatherByCity(this.state.search);
        console.log(this.state.search)
    };
    render() {
console.log(this.props.currentWeather);
        return (
            <View style={styles.container}>
                <MapView style={{flex : 1}}
                         region={{latitude : this.props.currentWeather ? this.props.currentWeather.coord.lat : DEFAULT_COORD.lat, longitude : this.props.currentWeather ? this.props.currentWeather.coord.lon : DEFAULT_COORD.lng, latitudeDelta: 0.2000, longitudeDelta: 0.1000}}
                         scrollEnabled={false}
                         liteMode={true} />
                {this.props.currentWeather &&
                <WeatherCard currentWeather={this.props.currentWeather}> </WeatherCard> }
                <SearchBar
                    lightTheme
                    onChangeText={this.updateSearch}
                    value={this.state.search}
                    onSubmitEditing={this.submitSearch}
                    containerStyle={{
                        position: "absolute",
                        bottom: hp("50%"),
                        left: wp("5%"),
                        width: wp("90%")

                    }}/>



            </View>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1

    },
});
const mapStateToProps = (store) => {
    return {
        currentWeather : store.weather.currentWeather
    }
};
const mapDispatchToProps = {
    getCurrentWeatherByCity
};
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(SearchScreen)
```

I really don't understand what I am doing wrong so if I can get help it would be awesome.
I'm a beginner so don't flame me if i'm doing some crap but any advices are welcomed !

Comment: You need to explain clearly what kind of error did you get. Make sure people understand deeper the problem you are facing with. Is your app working properly but the tab not showing?

Comment: Hello @Marfin.F ! Thanls for your answer. In fact i tried to add it but it never works, sometimes it just dosn't appear but app going well, sometimes my app is just broken. Actually I put my code without tabNavigator, just to have a hint where to start :)

Comment: Have you try this documentation? https://reactnavigation.org/docs/tab-based-navigation
Make sure you know which current version of your react-navigation library used.

Comment: Do you wish me for putting the example to your code?

Comment: @Marfin.F my version of react-navigation is ^3.1.5.
Yeah i checked but it was not a success :D
Yes it could be really awesome !

Comment: I have put the example as answer below. Let me know if it did not work :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have mentioned the version of your current react-navigation is ^3.1.5, I will give you an example to your project. For example, if you want to change that stackNavigator in your main screen (It means search and details screen will be accessed via tabs) then what you have to do is change it to createBottomNavigator. Then, your code should be like:

```
import SearchScreen from "./screens/search-screen";
import store from "./store";
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import { createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation'; //change this line
import AdvancedDetailScreen from "./screens/advanced-detail-screen";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
<Routes />
      </Provider>
  );
}
}

//change this to become tabnavigation
const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({ 
  Search : SearchScreen,
Detail: AdvancedDetailScreen
}); //Search will be default primary screen which is first to shown

const Routes = createAppContainer(StackNavigator);
```

**UPDATE**

Sorry since the configuration of createAppContainer in react-navigation v.3 it works like this. Yes, you can keep it both at the same file.

```
import SearchScreen from "./screens/search-screen";
import store from "./store";
import {Provider} from "react-redux"
import {createStackNavigator, createBottomTabNavigator, createAppContainer} from "react-navigation";
import AdvancedDetailScreen from "./screens/advanced-detail-screen";

export default class App extends React.Component {

  render() {

  return (
      <Provider store={store}>
<Routes />
      </Provider>
  );
}
}

const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Search : SearchScreen,
    Detail: AdvancedDetailScreen
},
    {
        initialRouteName: "Search",
        headerMode: "none"
    }
);

const TabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({ 
  Search : SearchScreen,
  Detail: AdvancedDetailScreen
}); //Put it together not working like this


const Routes = createAppContainer(TabNavigator, StackNavigator); //This line has been edited
```

It works but it means, you are trying to put tabs for every screen in your app. Because you put it with the route. Another example here: https://snack.expo.io/xu1Tiudf!

Documentation : https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/navigating
                https://reactnavigation.org/docs/3.x/tab-based-navigation

Comment: Oh thanks it's pretty great ! I'm understanding better now ! But is it possible to keep both ?

Comment: @Anatole Yes you can. And I updated my answer to provide the way to keep it both. :'D

Comment: @Anatole Tell me if you satisfy the answer, please check my answer as accepted answer. It will be helpful for people out there who looking for the answer related to react-navigation

Comment: Thanks but I can't put 2 arguments in the createAppContainer ! :)

Comment: @Anatole Strange. What error did you get? Because it works for me. Take a look here https://snack.expo.io/TCmCTs1Y1

Comment: @Anatole I think you have to put TabNavigator as first parameter inside createAppContainer then put StackNavigator as last parameter. Like in my updated answer

Comment: Oh sorry you're right ! My god thanks a lottttttt !!

Comment: @Anatole glad to hear that :D